# Rewrite Query_Var URL Parameter with Slug

Tags: query, rewrite-rules

I have a `query_var` set up for a search results page where my `query_var` is a taxonomy id used in a `WP_Query` loop, like:

`~/results/?my_taxoqueryvar=123`

I would like to implement a rewrite rule so that I can rewrite this so that it's a SEO friendlier, like:

`~/results/my-taxo-slug/` (where 'my-taxo-slug' is the corresponding slug for the taxonomy with ID 123.

I also want to be able to access my query var (i.e. `$qv_exp_type   = get_query_var('my_taxoqueryvar');`

This is what I have so far, but it doesn't appear to be working

```
// Add Query Var
function my_queryvar_params( $query_v ) {
    $query_v[] = "my_taxoqueryvar";
    return $query_v;
};
add_filter('query_vars',  'my_queryvar_params');


// Add Endpoint
function my_endpoint(){
    add_rewrite_endpoint( 'my_taxoqueryvar', EP_PAGES );
}
add_action( 'init', 'my_endpoint' );

function  my__rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'results/([a-z]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=results&my_taxoqueryvar=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
add_action('init',  'my_rewrite_rule' );
```

HUGE thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1):

Your rewrite rule and query vars filter is wrong. Below is an example based on your query var `my_taxoqueryvar`

```
function add_query_vars_filter( $vars ){
    $vars[] = "my_taxoqueryvar";
    return $vars;
}
add_filter( 'query_vars', 'add_query_vars_filter' );

add_action('init', 'myplugin_rewrite_rule' );
function myplugin_rewrite_rule() {
    add_rewrite_rule(
        'results/([a-z]+)/?$',
        'index.php?pagename=results&my_taxoqueryvar=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Tunji. I've updated the code in my question. Unfortunately though, the rewrite still doesn't appear to be taking effect (I've flushed rewrites).